# Changing background color without JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm a beginner to css and js. But I have a basic question I can't find an answer for on google: can I change a background color on a div on click without using javascript and jquery, just with css?

Comment: On hover yes, on click no.

Comment: css has no notion of a "click" :)

Comment: You could use the `:focus` selector, but I don't think that's the effect you're going for: http://jsfiddle.net/jamesallardice/NwXnz/

Comment: do you want the div color to change after clicking on the div itself or after clicking a link?

Comment: after clicking on a link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes that's possible with the `:target`selector and ids.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_the_:target_selector

HTML:

```
<div id="demo">Demo</div>
<a href="#demo">Click me</a>
```

CSS:

```
:target {
    background: green;
}
```

Demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/Qptjq/2/

Or even cooler:
http://jsfiddle.net/Qptjq/3/

`:target` requires IE9+ http://caniuse.com/#search=%3Atarget

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can.
you can try this:

HTML CODE

```
<div class="eventwheniclick">Hola amigo</div>
```

CSS CODE

```
.eventwheniclick{
    color:#4f4; 
    background:#0f0f0f;
}
.eventwheniclick:active,.eventwheniclick:focus{
    color:#f4f;
    background:#f0f0f0;

}
```

and live example here
http://jsbin.com/axawet/1/edit

Answer (score 0):

Here's something could help anyway: **(Onmouseover)**

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
.div1 {
    width:500px;
    height:300px;
    background:red;
}
.div1:hover {
    background:blue;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="div1"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, yes, but not in all browsers, so here's the trick.

**THE HTML**

```
<div id="myDiv">
</div>
```

**THE CSS**

```
#myDiv
{
    background-color:red;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    -webkit-transition: background 0s;
    -webkit-transition-delay: 99999s;
        -moz-transition: background 0s;
        -moz-transition-delay: 99999s;
            -o-transition: background 0s;
            -o-transition-delay: 99999s;
                transition: background 0s;
                transition-delay: 99999s;
}
#myDiv:active
{
    background-color:blue;
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
        -moz-transition-delay: 0s;
            -o-transition-delay: 0s;
                transition-delay: 0s;
}
```

So what will happen here? When you click on the div, the background will change in `0s`, however it will require `99999s` to turn back to red, and that's a lot of time, you may still increase it.

This is not something to really do, you need JavaScript, but its a just a trick, in case you really, really hate JavaScript.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/VYfzZ/1/)